# Calculate buffer size for string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to build a string of numbers based on a for loop from 0 to n-1, something like this:

```
char s[buffSize]
int position = 0;
for (i = 0; i< n-1; i++)
{
    position = sprintf(s+position, "%d ", i);
}
sprintf(s+position, "%d", i);
```

how would you calculate the necessary buffer size for s?
that be calculate size, give a rough larger size, allocate more size while looping? or any better more efficient trick.

it seems the sequence diverges.
solution I managed to build:

```
int calc_buffsize(int n) {
    int endpow = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", n);
    int pow = 1;
    int len = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < endpow; i++) {
      int newPow = pow * 10;
      len += ((newPow - pow) * i);
      pow = newPow;
    }
    return len + (n - pow) * i + n;
}
```

Comment: Try to find a formula, and use it, or set a maximal number and write an error and stop the loop when you reach the maximum, or allocate some buffer, if you need more, reallocate the double of size, and so on. "simple problem" where the details makes it more *interesting* (and not so simple)

Comment: Using `snprintf` would be one way. Your use of `sprintf` is wrong though.

Comment: I am using sprintf to calculate the size of the last number. Where am I Wrong and how should I use it?

Comment: Hint: logarithm.

Comment: Change `sprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", n);` to `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", n);`

Comment: Your use of `sprintf()` assumes you are calling `snprintf()`. You have a pointer and a length before the format which is what `snprintf()` requires.

Comment: true sorry, checked my code and it is snprintf instead fo sprintf

Comment: Don't write an approximation to your code into a question on SO.  Use copy and paste to ensure you show your exact code.

Comment: With 32-bit integers, each number can have up to 10 digits and a sign.  You can allocate 12 times the number of numbers to have enough space for each number plus a separator (comma) and the null terminator.

Comment: To my understanding, I can use logarithm to calculate the length of a number, using it instead of snprintf, but I have no idea if it can calculate the length of the sequence.

Comment: I like the 32 bit solution, that answers the rough larger number estimate part of the question.

Comment: Given that `i` starts from 0, you have: a zero, nine 1-digit numbers, ninety 2-digit numbers, nine hundred 3-digit numbers, nine thousand 4-digit numbers....   Spot a pattern?

Comment: yes, that is what calc_buffersize is for. based on your definition that is a 0, and then the series for any n could be badly  expressed by: 9*10^(n-1)  * n ? If you have Sn for this series... or maybe it is another series you have in mind. Any cool math solution is welcomed but please elaborate. Pardon my bad math terminology.

Comment: Ok, maybe I could use Example 3 (The sum of a geometric progression) from Knuths, since the value for each n can also be expressed as (10^n) - (10^n-1)

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can solve by exercise 15 in Knuth's, using the formula in exercise 16, divide the result by 10 and multiply by 9, this gives the following c code for calc_buffersize:

```
int calc_buffersize(int end)
{
    int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", end) -1;
    int len = 1 + ((pow(10, n)*(9*n-1) +1)/9);
    return len + end*(n+2) - pow(10,n)*(n+1);
}
```

Giacomo was correct that it is a simple yet interesting problem.

You can of course use it to calculate the buffer size for the string between two numbers:

```
int calc(int n, int num)
{
    return (pow(10, n) * (9 * n -1) + 1) / 9 
        + num * (2 + n) - pow(10, n) * (n + 1);
} 

int calc_buffersize(int end, int start)
{
    int n1 = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", end) -1;
    int n2 = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", start) -1;
    return calc(n1, end) - calc(n2, start);
}
```